# Iterating through a list to create values for the same set of keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I stripped and split a .csv file into a nested list that I want to become a nested dictionary. The main key should be the country and then the value should be a dictionary of the country's continent, gdp per capita, population, and area so it would look like this:

```
{'Luxembourg': {'continent': 'Europe', 'gdpPerCapita': 122740, 'population': 634730, 'area': 2586}, 
 'Singapore': {'continent': 'Asia', 'gdpPerCapita': 102742, 'population': 5453600, 'area': 728}
```

Except when I iterate through the list to define the values of the nested dictionary's keys, it stores the last country's information for every country. I know why it does this, but I don't know how to fix it.

```
country_dict={}
for i in data_list:
    country_dict['continent']=i[1]
    country_dict['gdpPerCapita']=i[2]
    country_dict['population']=i[3]
    country_dict['area']=i[4]
    data_dict[i[0]]= country_dict
```

Comment: could you please also provide `data_list` ?

Comment: move `country_dict = {}` inside the for loop.

Answer (score 3):

Dictionaries are mutable, you are setting the reference of `data_dict[i[0]]` to point to the variable `country_dict` which points to a single dictionary, that you are overwriting in every loop.

Set the `country_dict` to a new dictionary within the loop:

```
for i in data_list:
    country_dict={}
    country_dict['continent']=i[1]
    country_dict['gdpPerCapita']=i[2]
    country_dict['population']=i[3]
    country_dict['area']=i[4]
    data_dict[i[0]]= country_dict
```

or:

```
for i in data_list:
    data_dict[i[0]] = {
        'condinent':i[1],
        'gdpPerCapita':i[2],
        'population':i[3],
        'area':i[4]
    }
```